# How to import a movies.dat file in R from the attached link?

Tags: r

[enter link description here][1]

link from where you can download the data: http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/1m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

movies.dat is just a txt file with `::` as delim as described in the readme. So you can do the following:

```
txt <- readLines("./ml-1m/movies.dat", encoding = "latin1")
txt_split <- lapply(strsplit(txt, "::"), function(x) as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
dat <- do.call(rbind, txt_split)
names(dat) <- c("MovieID", "Title", "Genres")

dim(dat) # 3883    3
```

Which gives you:

```
dim(dat) # 3883    3
head(dat)

  MovieID                              Title                       Genres
1       1                   Toy Story (1995)  Animation|Children's|Comedy
2       2                     Jumanji (1995) Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3       3            Grumpier Old Men (1995)               Comedy|Romance
4       4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)                 Comedy|Drama
5       5 Father of the Bride Part II (1995)                       Comedy
6       6                        Heat (1995)        Action|Crime|Thriller
```

P.S.: I couldnt figure out how to use the "standard" R-read methods like `read.table`, `readr::read_delim` and `data.table::fread` as they need a 1-byte seperation. You could try to switch `::` to something else before reading the data using e.g. the sed CLI